# How to check different value keys in a dictionary concurrently using list comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to accomplish a task, but having some difficulty.Can someone set me straight on the following:

```
#This worked for me
myFormats = {'audio': ('.wav', '.wma', '.mp3'), 'video': ('.mpg', '.mp4', '.mpeg')}

myFile = '5DeadlyVenoms.mp3'
f_exten = (x for x in myFormats['audio'] + myFormats['video'] if myFile.endswith(x))
extension = f_exten.next()
```

Using the following resulted in this error:

```
myFormats = {'audio': {'.wav', '.wma', '.mp3'}, 'video': {'.avi', '.mpg', '.mp4', '.mpeg'}}
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\GVRSQA004\Desktop\udCombo.py", line 65, in fileFormats
f_exten = (x for x in myFormats['audio'] + myFormats['video'] if myFile.endswith(x))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\GVRSQA004\Desktop\udCombo.py", line 65, in fileFormats
f_exten = (x for x in myFormats['audio'] + myFormats['video'] if myFile.endswith(x))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to return, and also post the rest of the code (the line that errors isn't in the first snippet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your mistake:

```
myFormats['audio'] or myFormats['video']
```

This will **always** simply return `myFormats['audio']`, because this is a logical `or`. What you wanted instead was the two tuples appended:

```
myFormats['audio'] + myFormats['video']
```

---

An even better solution is using `set`'s and a generator:

```
formats = {'audio': {'.wav', '.wma', '.mp3'}, 'video': {'.mpg', '.mp4', '.mpeg'}}

myfile = '5DeadlyVenoms.mp3'
extensions = (x for x in formats['audio'] + formats['video'] if myfile.endswith(x))
extension = extensions.next()
```

Comment: Using a dictionary instead of sets worked for me. When I tried sets I got the updated traceback error.

Answer (score 1):

```
[x for v in myFormats.itervalues() for x in v if myFile.endswith(x)]
```

returns

```
['.mp3']
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want a list of all matching file extensions?  It looks like you're just using the first one.

If not:

```
>>> myFormats = {'audio': {'.wav', '.wma', '.mp3'}, 'video': {'.mpg', '.mp4', '.mpeg'}}
>>>
>>> myFile = '5DeadlyVenoms.mp3'
...
>>> def get_extension(file_name, formats):
...     for key, extensions in formats.items():
...         for extension in extensions:
...             if file_name.endswith(extension):
...                 return extension
...
>>> myFile_extension = get_extension(myFile, myFormats)
>>> myFile_extension
'.mp3'
```

This would allow you to easily modify it to return the key (i.e. audio or video) if you needed it, or turn it into a generator if you wanted multiple extensions.